# RxJava objects taking too much time to be initialized

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I'm using such construction to handle multiple data loading responses. The problem in that this code affects on fragment start time (+2 about second). `load()` function is placed into `ViewModel`. `Fragment#onResume()` method calls `ViewModel#load()` method. How can I optimize this code to reduce `Fragment` startup time?

```
fun load() {
    Single.zip(
            apiDataManager1.getSingle().subscribeOnIo().observeOnMain(),
            apiDataManager2.getSingle().subscribeOnIo().observeOnMain(),
            apiDataManager3.getSingle().subscribeOnIo().observeOnMain(),
            Function3<Any, Any, Any, Unit> { _, _, _ ->
             // process data
            }
        )
            .subscribeOnIo()
            .observeOnMain()
            .subscribe()
}
```

### UPD

If I wrap this function into `Thread {}` everything works fine. How can I do this only with Rx?

Comment: I am new to Rx world but afaik this zip won't be initialised until all your apiDataManager1, apiDataManager2 and apiDataManager3 emits data.

Comment: What is `observeOnMain()` exactly? Is it `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`?

Comment: @Tuby, yep. Kotlin extension

Answer (score 0):

try start the chain with something else, specify observer. not sure it is inteneded but combining data in Function3 probably shouldn't be deliveded to main thread:

```
  Single.defer(() -> Single.just(true))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap( any -> Single.zip(
               apiDataManager1.getSingle().subscribeOnIo(),
               apiDataManager2.getSingle().subscribeOnIo(),
               apiDataManager3.getSingle().subscribeOnIo(), { _, _, _ ->
              // process data
               })).subscribeOnIo()
        .observeOnMain()
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: Looks like a crunch. It's easier to wrap `Single.zip`  into coroutine